# Drupal error. Drupal safe mode possible?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I added organic groups module to a drupal website. For some reason the website crashed and gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/content/39/7384539/html/salvare12/sites/default/modules/og/includes/og.info inc on line 115
```

I removed the organic groups module manually and disabled it in the database. But then it gives a file missing error. I have uploaded the organic groups module once again but it does not work.

How can this be fixed? Is there some **safe mode** in drupal, to which i can revert when such an error occurs?

Comment: Have you run update.php in the URL?

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the row for the og module in the system table. Then run a query for each database table beginning with cache_:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_*
```

This should make Drupal forget anything it knew about organic groups (this is how to clear the cache manually).

I'd suggest keeping your modules in the standard location which is /sites/all/modules rather than /sites/default. I don't know if thats part of the problem here but it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I'd get to know [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) and use that to disable and uninstall (where available) modules until your site is back up again.